# Can't set png image through css content property in Symfony project

Tags: css, symfony

My png image is located in `src/AppBundle/Resources/public/img`

I am trying to set png image through css `content` property:

```
content: url(../../public/assets/img/optional-checked.png);
```

But I am getting

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/public/assets/img/optional-checked.png 404 (Not Found)
```

How can I set png image through CSS content property in Symfony project?

Comment: Use asset keyword.

Comment: if your image located in `public/img` why you search it in `public/assets/img`?

Answer (score 1):

First suggestion, That's because you need to respect the hierarchy from where you call your CSS not your script.

Another suggestion would be not to use `public` folder to upload your `assets`, instead of this, use `web` folder (in the root), because if you do like I'm saying then the twig views can use properly `asset` keyword right.

And the last tip, is that you are trying to read your image from `public/assets/img/optional-checked.png` when you said that your image is really located in `public/img`.

Hope this helps.